# How to web scrape data from the second page?

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I want to web scrape data using the functions from the rvest library. Loading the website and using a form works fine. But when I want to access the data I only get access to 35 of the available >70 table entries. The data are automatically split into chunks of 35 entries.

On the actual website, these data would be available with a nextPage-button (.rgPageNext  RESPECTIVELY //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "rgPageNext", " " ))]). However, I do not know how to include this into the code to get access to the other entries.

```
# library
library(rvest)    

# load html session
ua <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
mainPage  <-'https://www.tsis.fli.de/Reports/Info_SO.aspx?ts=416&guid=d04e759d-7cf0-48da-b730-4d7f397531e2'

# use form on session
session <- html_session(mainPage, httr::user_agent(ua))
pgform <- html_form(session)[[1]]
pgform$fields[['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblActiveMode']]$value =  "1"
filledform <- set_values(pgform)
result <- submit_form(session, filledform)

# load the entries 1-35
result %>%  
  html_nodes("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgSO_ctl00") %>%
  html_text()
```